# Python program using python class improves speed?

Tags: python, performance

I'm doing another Leetcode "1202. Smallest String With Swaps".  The code below managed 35/36 cases but exceeded time for one.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Solution:

    def smallestStringWithSwaps(self, s, pairs):

        nofNode = len(s)
        parents = list(range(nofNode))
        def findParent(child):
            if child == parents[child]: return child
            else:
                return findParent(parents[child])
        def union(a, b):
            parents[findParent(a)] = findParent(b)

        for a, b in pairs:
            union(a, b)
        for i in range(nofNode):
            parents[i] = findParent(parents[i])
        dic = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(nofNode):
            dic[findParent(i)].append(s[i])
        for key in dic.keys():
            dic[key].sort(reverse=True)
        res = []
        for i in range(nofNode):
            res.append(dic[findParent(i)].pop())

        return ''.join(res)
```

The way to resolve this is to **create a class and move the functions into a class**.  Also **move the parents (python list) into the class**.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Solution:

    def smallestStringWithSwaps(self, s, pairs):

        class UF:
            def __init__(self, n): self.p = list(range(n))

            def union(self, x, y): self.p[self.findParent(x)] = self.findParent(y)

            def findParent(self, x):
                if x != self.p[x]: self.p[x] = self.findParent(self.p[x])
                return self.p[x]

        uf = UF(len(s))
        for a, b in pairs:
            uf.union(a, b)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            uf.p[i] = uf.findParent(uf.p[i])
        dic = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            dic[uf.findParent(i)].append(s[i])
        for key in dic.keys():
            dic[key].sort(reverse=True)
        res = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            res.append(dic[uf.findParent(i)].pop())

        return ''.join(res)
```

Why does using a class solves improve the timing ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm highly skeptical this would improve the timing. I haven't done detailed experiments with 3.10, but in prior versions of CPython, closures simulating classes with nested scope acting as state almost always beat equivalent classes (much like generator functions beat hand-written iterator classes). My guess is jitter in the code execution got unlucky with one of your tests, and lucky the second time around.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I didn't believe the class would help. I model my "function program" from another using "class".  I've first test the class and it worked.  So I was very puzzled with the function version.  I tried optimising at every possible way until I converted the "function" to class.  Then it beat the timing.